# Как запускать браузер через прокси в firefox selenium

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, firefox

`options` который использовался во всех способах:

```
user_agent = UserAgent()
user_agent = user_agent.random

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.set_preference('general.useragent.override', user_agent)
options.set_preference('dom.webdriver.enabled', False)
```

1 - с таким способом остается мой ip:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType

...

proxy = Proxy({
    'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
    'httpProxy': 'xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx',
    'ftpProxy': 'xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx',
    'sslProxy': 'xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx',
    'noProxy': ''
    })

driver = webdriver.Firefox(
    executable_path=path,
    options=options,
    proxy='xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx'
)
```

2 - с таким способом также остается мой ip:

```
firefox_capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True

firefox_capabilities['selected_proxy'] = {
    'proxyType': 'MANUAL',
    'httpProxy': 'xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx',
    'ftpProxy': 'xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx',
    'sslProxy': 'xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx'
}

browser = webdriver.Firefox(
    executable_path=path,
    options=options,
    proxy='xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx'
```

3 - с таким способом все равно остается мой ip:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http", proxy_host)
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", int(proxy_port))
fp.update_preferences()

browser = webdriver.Firefox(
    executable_path=path,
    options=options,
    firefox_profile=fp
)
```

4 - на такой способ возвращается это исключение `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: Invalid proxy configuration entry: autodetect`

```
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy": 'xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx',
    "ftpProxy": 'xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx',
    "sslProxy": 'xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx',
    "noProxy":None,
    "proxyType":"MANUAL",
    "autodetect":False
}
```

5 - на такой - это исключение `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page`:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

fp.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http",PROXY_HOST)
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port",int(PROXY_PORT))
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.https",PROXY_HOST)
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.https_port",int(PROXY_PORT))
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl",PROXY_HOST)
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl_port",int(PROXY_PORT))  
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ftp",PROXY_HOST)
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.ftp_port",int(PROXY_PORT))   
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.socks",PROXY_HOST)
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_port",int(PROXY_PORT))   

fp.update_preferences()

kbrowser = webdriver.Firefox(
    executable_path=path,
    options=options,
    firefox_profile=fp
)
```

6 - еще одно исключение и то же что и было, может это означает плохой прокси и на самом деле способ рабочий? `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page`

```
prox = Proxy()
prox.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL

prox.http_proxy = 'xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx'
prox.ssl_proxy = 'xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx'

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
prox.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)

browser = webdriver.Firefox(↲                                                                                                
    executable_path=path,
    options=options,                                                                              
    desired_capabilities=capabilities                                                                               
)
```

7 - возвращает мой ip

```
http_proxy  = "http://ip:port"
https_proxy = "https://ip:port"

proxyDict = {
    "http"  : http_proxy,
    "https" : https_proxy,
                }

driver = webdriver.Firefox(
    executable_path=path,
    options=options,
    proxy=proxyDict
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

тоже долго мучился с прокси в селениуме. в итоге написал расширение через которое ставлю теперь прокси и куки. https://github.com/alexsok-bit/selenium_helper